# How get rid of redundant wrapper object of a mutation result?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

When I'm making a request to my backend through a mutation like that:

```
mutation{
  resetPasswordByToken(token:"my-token"){
    id
  }
}
```

I'm getting a response in such format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "resetPasswordByToken": {
      "id": 3
    }
  }
}
```

And that wrapper object named the same as the mutation seems somewhat awkward (and at least redundant) to me. Is there a way to get rid of that wrapper to make the returning result a bit cleaner?

This is how I define the mutation now:

```js
export const ResetPasswordByTokenMutation = {
    type: UserType,
    description: 'Sets a new password and sends an informing email with the password generated',
    args: {
        token: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        captcha: { type: GraphQLString },
    },
    resolve: async (root, args, request) => {
        const ip = getRequestIp(request);
        const user = await Auth.resetPasswordByToken(ip, args);
        return user.toJSON();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word: **No**.

`resetPasswordByToken` is not a "wrapper object", but simply a field you've defined in your schema that resolves to an object (in this case, a `UserType`). While it's common to request just one field on your `mutation` type at a time, it's possible to request any number of fields:

```
mutation {
  resetPasswordByToken(token:"my-token"){
    id
  }
  someOtherMutation {
    # some fields here
  }
  andYetAnotherMutation {
    # some other fields here
  }
}
```

If we were to flatten the structure of the response like you suggest, we would not be able to distinguish between the data returned by one mutation from another. We likewise need to nest all of this inside `data` to keep our actual data separate from any returned errors (which appear in a separate `errors` entry).